# How to upper bound this quantity?

Tags: matrices, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

Let $M,\tilde{M},P, \tilde{P}, Q$ and $\tilde{Q}$ be $n\times n$ non singular matrices. Assume $P$ and $\tilde{P}$ are orthogonal, and let $b$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that the following inequalities are given:

$\|\tilde{M}-M \|\le \epsilon _1$
$\|\tilde{P} -P \| \le \epsilon_2$ and
$\|\tilde{Q}-Q\|\le \epsilon_3$.

How can I use such information to upper bound the quantity
$\|\tilde{M}\tilde{P}\tilde{Q}\tilde{P}^Tb - MPQP^Tb\|$?

Answer (score 0):

try to continue like this by inserting some creative zeros
$$
\tilde M \tilde P \tilde Q \tilde P^T
= (\tilde M-M)\tilde P \tilde Q \tilde P^T
+ M \tilde P \tilde Q \tilde P^T \\
=  (\tilde M-M)\tilde P \tilde Q \tilde P^T
+ M (\tilde P -P)\tilde Q \tilde P^T   + MP\tilde Q \tilde P^T\\
= \dots
$$